# How to Store and access Dictionary Object in Array

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I would like to store dictionary object in array but I am getting an error. is there any way which I can store dictionary in array

```
Sub aaa()

    Dim arr(5)
    'arr(0) = 100   
     Set dict_123 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     dict_123.Add "first", 300
     dict_123.Add "Second", 500    
     arr(0) = dict_123   

End Sub
```

Error is Wrong number of Arguments or invalid property assignment at  "arr(0) = dict_123 "

Comment: You want to store an object reference, you need to `Set` that reference. `Set arr(0) = dict_123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

1. Use `Option Explicit` to check variable declarations
2. Declare your dictionary as `Object`
3. As it is an object you need to use the `set` keyword when adding to array

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub aaa()

    Dim arr(5)
    Dim dict_123 As Object
    Set dict_123 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict_123.Add "first", 300
    dict_123.Add "Second", 500
    Set arr(0) = dict_123

End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

As function

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DoSomeThing()
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = aaa()(0)
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print dict(key)
    Next key
End Sub

Public Function aaa() As Variant
    Dim arr(5)
    Dim dict_123 As Object
    Set dict_123 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict_123.Add "first", 300
    dict_123.Add "Second", 500
    Set arr(0) = dict_123
    aaa = arr
End Function
```

Comment: if I write "aaa" as function and called it from the other sub. how can I return the array and how can I access the dictionary data in the sub?

Comment: Can't we loop over the Dictionary in DoSomeThing like                       For Each k In dict.keys
       dict (k)
    Next         I am getting an error  Object doesn't support this property at dict(k)

Comment: @ QHarr,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792960/how-to-return-array-and-assign-to-array-from-calling-function    can you please help me from the question mention in link. because of the space I opened one more question.