# Returning Array and assign to array from calling function

Tags: vba

```
Public Sub DoSomeThing()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim arr2(5)
    Set arr2() = aaa()

   For m = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        Set dict = aaa()(m)
        Dim key As Variant
       For Each key In dict.Keys
           Debug.Print dict(key)
       Next key
  Next
End Sub

Public Function aaa() As Variant
    Dim arr(5)
   Dim dict_123 As Object
   For k = 1 To 2
       If k = 1 Then
           val1 = 300
           val2 = 500
       ElseIf k = 2 Then
           val1 = 600
           val2 = 1200
      End If
       Set dict_123 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
       dict_123.Add "first", val1
       dict_123.Add "Second", val2
       Set arr(k) = dict_123
   Next
  aaa = arr
End Function
```

Here I want to get return the Array from `aaa` to the `DoSomething` and process that array from `DoSomeThing`. How can I do that?

I am getting the error as  can't assign to Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of errors and I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve overall. Your code above "fixed" below.

Notes:

1. `arr2 = aaa` set one array equal to the other (no set keyword as not object). Do not dimension `arr2` first.
2. Test if current array (`arr2`) item is a dictionary before attempting the set. You have only added dictionaries at index 1 and 2 in the 0 based array. Less robust would be `If m = 1 Or m = 2`
3. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables
4. I prefer a `Select Case` in the function to `If` statement particularly if you want to add more conditions where you may want the same result for more than one condition.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomeThing()
    Dim dict As Object, arr2, m As Long, key As Variant
    arr2 = aaa  '<==Set one array equal to the other (no set keyword as not object)

    For m = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
       If TypeName(arr2(m)) = "Dictionary"  ' <== We can test if current array item is a dictionary before attempting the set. You have only added dictionaries at position 1 and 2 in the array. Less robust would be If m = 1 Or m = 2
            Set dict = arr2(m)   '<==index into your arr2 array
            For Each key In dict.Keys
                Debug.Print dict(key)
            Next key
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function aaa() As Variant
   Dim arr(5), k As Long, val1 As Long, val2 As Long, dict_123 As Object
   For k = 1 To 2
       Select Case k '<== Use select statement 
       Case 1
           val1 = 300
           val2 = 500
       Case 2
           val1 = 600
           val2 = 1200
      End Select
      Set dict_123 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      dict_123.Add "first", val1
      dict_123.Add "Second", val2
      Set arr(k) = dict_123 'K starts at 1 so position 0 is empty; as are positions after 2.
   Next k
   aaa = arr

End Function
```

Comment: - Thanks, you clarified better than I would have+

Comment: @Sorry for the mistakes, I actually tried without option Explicit, so I am not faced many errors,.....Thanks for the detailed help....